# Paste absolute references in a formula but increase by 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has formulas spread over the sheet (averaging around five cells between them).

I want to copy a formula from say A1 and paste it into cell A6 but have the formula only increment the cell reference by 1.

For example:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(sheet1!$a$2),"",sheet1!$a$2)
```

And paste this into cell A7 but have the absolute reference now be

```
=IF(ISBLANK(sheet1!$a$3),"",sheet1!$a$3)
```

There are about 200 of these to add to the sheet so I'd rather not manually edit each one.

Comment: There's no way to do this automatically *unless* the pattern is entirely deterministic. Is the pattern deterministic?

Comment: Was just about to say the same as @ImaginaryHuman072889 but you could perhaps create a macro on keypress to simulate this, assigned to say Ctrl+Alt+V instead, use a single cell as a counter for the row or something in the name manager, but always give VBA a go first even if it doesn't work so we can give you pointers to help out rather than free code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INDEX on column A and some maths to create the stagger.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/5)+1)), "", INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/5)+1))
```

I suppose  that INT could be replaced by ROUND for a 'fuzzy' stagger *'averaging around 5 cells between them'*.

Other possibilities for incrementing the stagger could be COUNT, COUNTA, COUNTIF or even COUNTIFS but you haven't provided enough information to base any concrete suggestions upon beyond generalities.

Comment: That would be for a constant algebraic pattern, right? Going from A6 to A7 wouldn't make the increment rise, it appears the OP's structure isn't consistent

Comment: My tired old eyes added my addendum to the wrong response. See my additional; narrative above.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Indirect in that way :

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$" & ROW()+1)),"",INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$" & ROW()+1))
```

If you like using VBA you can use this simple loop

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Long

    For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 6
        Cells(r, 1).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A$" & r + 1 & "),"""",Sheet1!$A$" & r + 1 & ")"
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: fwiw, the `""""` can be replaced with `TEXT(,)` to avoid dooubling up double quotes within a quoted string.